# BST: deleting node with 2 children in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I implemented recursive algorihtm for deleting nodes in BST, but it seems not to work properly in case in which the node to be deleted has two children. Here is a code for method used to delete nodes:

```
public boolean delete(int val)
{


    Node nodeToBeDeleted = find(val);
    if(nodeToBeDeleted != null)
    {
        //case 1: node has no children
        if(nodeToBeDeleted.leftChild == null && nodeToBeDeleted.rightChild == null)
            deleteCase1(nodeToBeDeleted);

        //case 3: node has two children
        else if(nodeToBeDeleted.leftChild != null && nodeToBeDeleted.rightChild != null)
        {
            deleteCase3(nodeToBeDeleted);
        }

        //case 2: node has one child
        else if(nodeToBeDeleted.leftChild != null)
        {
            //case 2 where left child should be deleted
            deleteCase2(nodeToBeDeleted);
        }

        else if(nodeToBeDeleted.rightChild != null)
        {
            //case 2 where right child should be deleted
            deleteCase2(nodeToBeDeleted);
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

And here deleteCase1, deleteCase2 and deleteCase3 methods:

```
private void deleteCase1(Node nodeToBeDeleted)
{
        //check if node to be deleted is a left or a right child of the parent of the node to be deleted
        if(nodeToBeDeleted.parent.leftChild == nodeToBeDeleted)
        {
            nodeToBeDeleted.parent.leftChild = null;
        }
        else if(nodeToBeDeleted.parent.rightChild == nodeToBeDeleted)
        {
            nodeToBeDeleted.parent.rightChild = null;
        }
}
```

Here find method:

```
public Node find(int val)
{
    if(root != null)
    {
        return findNode(root, new Node(val));
    }

    return null;
}

private Node findNode(Node search, Node node)
{
    if(search == null)
        return null;

    if(search.data == node.data)
    {
        return search;
    }
    else
    {
        Node returnNode = findNode(search.leftChild, node);

        if(returnNode == null)
        {
            returnNode = findNode(search.rightChild, node);
        }

        return returnNode;
    }
}
```

minLeftTreversal method:

```
private Node minLeftTreversal(Node node)
{
    if(node.leftChild == null)
        return node;

    return minLeftTreversal(node.leftChild);
}
```

Structure of the tree looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4xaJ.png)

Algorithm works if I delete 75, but if I try to delete 25 it messes up.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your first if statement in `public boolean delete(int val)` is missing the `{` and `}`

```
        //case 1: node has no children
        if(nodeToBeDeleted.leftChild == null && nodeToBeDeleted.rightChild == null)
        { // <---- ADD THIS
            deleteCase1(nodeToBeDeleted);
        } // <---- AND ADD THIS
        //case 3: node has two children
        else if(nodeToBeDeleted.leftChild != null && nodeToBeDeleted.rightChild != null)
        {
            deleteCase3(nodeToBeDeleted);
        }
```